# PHP has encountered an Access Violation at 01BAB0EF

Tags: windows-server-2003, php, iis-6

I was putting some css style for texts in a php file and after saving, I got this error:
PHP has encountered an Access Violation at 01BAB0EF

Even I deleted that php file but still I can't load my website!! what happened?

Comment: Definitely NOT a css issue...

Answer (score 2):

Contact your hosting provider, PHP shouldn't crash like this. Btw, is this a Win32 based host running PHP? Yuk.

Comment: Yes, it's Win Server 2003 with IIS6 running php5

Answer (score 0):

PHP died hard, and probably took a chunk of IIS with it. Try restarting IIS, or even the entire server if it's possible

If at all possible, try moving to LAMP for PHP hosting. I've yet to see a Windows AMP stack that works well enough to be production-ready.

Comment: An application fault that is not making the system more unstable. That's why the kernel got the exception - to avoid the system instability. And the fact that he is seeing the error in a web page, means that IIS is running fine.

Comment: IIS is running fine, PHP is not. Restarting IIS generally restarts all websites and dependent services, which may clear a transient error.